# convert value to datatype in string format

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, web-applications, combobox

I an c# beginner and working in web development using Silver Light-5 in Visual Studio-2010. I have my GUI on running my code which has it's GUI created by xaml and the button clicks are handled in c#.

Now what i have to achieve is :

I am trying to create a GUI in which i use combo box which will contain options like this (please see this link) http://prntscr.com/36l58s In this link i select the one datatype among the 5 given datatypes (which are byte,sbyte,short,int,long). And after that i want to assign this datatype to a variable in c# code like this: (suppose i selected "short" in that).
then i want to assign it to a variable (suppose "varble" here) like this `short varble =1000;`

How to do that ?

My xaml code for it is :

and c# code for it is (Inside the constructor) :

```
            comboBox1.Items.Add("byte");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("sbyte");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("short");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("int");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("long");
```

and button click event of ComboBox is :

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Why i am trying to do this? :

Actually ,i was just trying to create a GUI where i can select the datatype of variable at run time among the given specified options and i guess using combobox is best suitable. This selected dataType (for example short in previous example) that selected  dataType i then assign to a variable in my code in c#.(Actually i am reading i binary file and i have to select the byte read to store in a variable which must have options of dataType (like short,int,long) in 16/32/64 bit integer which is supposed to be selected by COMBO Box). Could you please help me in doing that ? Thanks a lot (If my logic don't work and you have other alternative then please tell me with full details because i am just a beginner). Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can get idea from below code sample :

```
var selectedDatatype = "String";
var valueToConvert = 1;
var convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(valueToConvert, Type.GetType("System." + selectedDatatype));
```

**Note:** make sure that items populated in dropdown belongs to **`System`** namespace. So instead of long you should use `Int64`

Comment: thanks do this i have to keep in switch case statement where "string" is selected data type in combo box and it will be particular case when "string" is selected.If , Yes then could you be please more explain using a switch-case statement.

Comment: There is no need to keep in switch case statement while converting. Assign the selected value of Combobox to `var selectedDataType` variable.

Comment: But make sure that when you select `long` then its combobox value should be 'Int64'. and same for `byte` to `Byte`, `short` to `Int16` etc...

Comment: Error1 : No overload for method 'ChangeType' takes 2 arguments  and pointing the line "Convert.ChangeType(valueToConvert, Type.GetType("System." + selectedDatatype));"

Comment: And why there is "1" assigned to "valueToConvert" ? and How it will receive the data type selected by ComboBox ? Because i am not able to understand anything by your code. Could you please explain bit more. Thank you so much

Comment: As i mentioned, that is code sample. you can get an idea from it and implement it as per your requirement.